# IIS web.config inheritance with .Net Core

Tags: iis, .net-4.0, web-config, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to redesign one of the system's module using Asp.Net Core and host it inside IIS server. So, I just need to replace already existing ASP.NET Web Forms app with the .Net Core based API. But the tricky part here that I still have to use upper level web.config file(s) and fetch configuration parameters from it.

I did brief research and found out that it may be a problem cause the configuration mechanism was changed and it's not recommended to use XML based we.config or app.config any more and I should use app.settings instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I found this very nice article https://wildermuth.com/2018/04/15/Building-a-NET-Core-Configuration-Source about how to build custom configuration source and provider and now I can even extract app setting from the local web.config file but still experiencing the problem with getting access to the upper level web.config file.

When I do this

```
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            config
                .AddWebConfig("web.config", optional: true)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
        })
```

I can successfully find and parse web.config file, but when I try to find web.config in an upper level like this

```
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            config
                .AddWebConfig("..\\web.config", optional: false)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
        })
```

I get en error message

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The configuration file
>   '..\web.config' was not found and is not optional.'

Any recommendations about how to get access to upper level web.config file would be very much appreciated!

Unfortunately I can't skip this part and this is one of the client's business requirements.

Comment: Based on the source code, relative file path might not be supported. You might try to use absolute file path instead.

Comment: Nope, absolute file path didn't help at all... got the same error :( Maybe it's relater some how to the access limitation and the process just doesn't have any access to the files except the ones that belong to the project?

Comment: ASP.NET Core is fully open sourced, so your only hope is to debug the code, instead of guessing the cause out. "Unfortunately I can't skip this part and this is one of the client's business requirements" is also something weird, as requirements are negotiable. The nice article you found only pretends to solve the issue, but it is far from the complete ASP.NET configuration system for 4.x.